# Using lambda environment variable to pass parameters to cloudwatch api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using environment variables in Lambda to collect list of alarm names, then pass it to the AlarmNames field in Cloudwatch API cloudwatch.describe_alarms(AlarmNames=[])

Keep having error in type, the type that is accepted by the API is list and tuple.

```
env = os.environ['ALARM_NAMES']
response = cloudwatch.describe_alarms(
    AlarmNames= env
)
```

this are the environment variables field for ALARM_NAMES:
'instance1-freediskspace C','instance2-freediskspace C','instance3-freediskspace C'

Comment: How is ALARM_NAMES being set? Can you print the env here and update the question with an example value?

Comment: updated with sample values in environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables are strings. To get a tuple or a list you can split the string by some separator:

```
"mystring1;mystring2".split(";")  # -> ['mystring1', 'mystring2']
```

Comment: the function able to run without errors, but the describe_alarms failed to return any results, this means that none of the env variables were passed into the argument list

Answer (score 1):

If this is the value of `env`:

```
"'instance1-freediskspace C','instance2-freediskspace C','instance3-freediskspace C'"
```

you need to remove the single quotes and split by the comma to get the list. Like this for example:

```
AlarmNames= env.replace("'", "").split(',')
```